# git tree object filename charset encode

Tags: git, character-encoding, encode

when i add and commit a new file, file name is "À".
the char 'À' is not ascii, and use the command

> git cat-file -p  master^{tree}

the result:

> 100644 blob 78981922613b2afb6025042ff6bd878ac1994e85  "\303\200"

I know the string "\303\200" is the filename "À", but how it come from?

how git cat-file encode non-ascii char filename?

Answer (score 2):

It is stored in [UTF-8 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). What you see is this encoding represented in C-style [octal notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

The letter “À” is Unicode character 192, or `00011000000` in binary. According to the rules for UTF-8, this is put into two bytes `110xxxxx` and `10xxxxxx`, thus `11000011` and `10000000`. For octal notation, these are grouped `11-000-011` (`303`, decimal 3*8²+3 = 195) and `10-000-000` (`200`, decimal 2*8² = 128).